# Why does this tkinter grid center the checkbox added at the end?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pycharm, python-3.8

[image: this is how i get the output]I am not able to figure out that how column span is working. I know this sounds a bit foolish but,
i was just confused on seeing the output, how the checkbox is put automatically below the password input box(entry2 box).

## use of grid()

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
label1 = Label(root,text='Name:')
label2 = Label(root,text='Password:')
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry2 = Entry(root)
label1.grid(row=0,column=0)
entry1.grid(row=0,column=1)
label2.grid(row=1,column=0)
entry2.grid(row=1,column=1)

c = Checkbutton(root,text='Keep me logged in')
c.grid(columnspan=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yeah i found out that columnspan is used to merge two columns into one, but the confusion is that how is it put in the 1st column rather than the 0th column.

Comment: Generally speaking, "please explain this code" questions are considered too broad to be topical here, unless they're _very_ specific about what you don't understand. Making the title more specific will thus do a lot of good to avoid downvotes/close votes. See [How to deal with questions of the type "I don't understand how this code works"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797) on [meta].

Comment: Maybe edit the title to something like "Why does this tkinter grid center the checkbox added at the end?", if that does in fact represent what you mean to ask; edit to fit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh, yes i should have done it before thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of the default values of "column" and "row" (see below)

`column` : Insert the widget at this column. Column numbers start with 0. If omitted, defaults to 0.

`row` : Insert the widget at this row. Row numbers start with 0. If omitted, defaults to the first empty row in the grid.
Hence, the check button defaults to the first column, and the first empty row, which is row 3.

For more, see: https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: Sir, but the check box should put itself in first(zeroth) column, i guess.....

Comment: @Dharman sir, in the output the checkbox is put on the 1st column and not the 0th

Comment: There is no 1st column in that row as it is merged with the 0th column.  That is 0th column of that row is a big cell across two columns.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `c.grid(columnspan=2)` is exactly the same as `c.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)`. When you don't explicity set a row and column, row defaults to the next empty row and column defaults to zero.

Thus, you are putting the checkbutton in row 2, and it spans columns 0 and 1. Since you aren't using the `sticky` attribute, the default behavior is to be centered in the space that was allotted to it.

If your main goal is to have it left-aligned, just add `sticky="w"` when calling `grid`:

```
c.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="w")
```